# Create a JSON String in Swift

Tags: ios, json, string, serialization, swift3

I send the text from a TextView to my Backend. To include linebreaks, i try to serialize the textView.text to JSON.

```
let jsonObject: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    jsonObject.setValue(textView.text, forKey: "text")

    let jsonData: NSData

    do {
        jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()) as NSData
        let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
        print(jsonString)

    } catch _ {
        print ("JSON Failure")
    }

    }
```

But since this is a Dictionary, the resulting text looks like this: 
{"text":"test\nstack\n\noverflow"}

i actually just need: **test\nstack\n\noverflow**

Is there a pretty way to transform a multiline String in swift to have these "\n" for linebreaks without any extra characters?

Edit:

I expect to type into my textView something like this: [image]

and as a result get the string "hello\n\n"

The source looks like this:

```
let text = textView.text
        let components = text?.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).filter({!$0.isEmpty})
        let textWithLineFeeds = components?.joined(separator:"\n")

        print(textWithLineFeeds!)
        print(textView.text)
```

the first print gives: 
test
hello
linebreak above

the second print statement:
test
hello

linebreak above

i wish i could see:
test\nhello\n\nlinebreak above

Comment: Why don't you deserialize the JSON in your backend and get the text value from the "text" key? :)

Comment: not my backend, just the backend i have to develop for. i could use textview.text.debugdescription and trim the first and the last character, but i do not want to use a hacky solution.

Comment: I don't get it. Doesn't the backend understand JSON, since you're sending JSON? If the backend doesn't understand JSON, just send a string instead of JSON... Please explain, I'm not following why you can't send your JSON object.

Comment: If you want to send only the string why do you serialize the string at all? A single JSON string is equal to a standard string. However it's recommended to send JSON with an array or dictionary as root object. And **never** use `NSMutableArray / NSMutableDictionary` in Swift

Comment: i send to the backend a json with the following headers,  let headers2: HTTPHeaders = [
            "sid": sid,
            "receiver": guid,
            "message": message,
            "latestmessage": "0"
        ], if the message string contains line breaks it wont accept it. it needs \n to process linebreaks. Thats why i tried to achieve this via json serialization. i just want to fill the linebreaks with \n and avoid any extra characters.

Answer (score 1):

To convert text with arbitrary new line characters (CR, LF, CRLF etc.) to distinct  - only LF - line breaks use:

```
let text = "test\r\nstack\n\noverflow\rfoo"
let components = text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).filter({!$0.isEmpty})
let textWithLineFeeds = components.joined(separator:"\n")
```

If the server accepts only CR, change `\n` to `\r`.

Comment: your answers converts "test\r\nstack\n\noverflow\rfoo" to
test
stack
overflow

but i need it the exact opposite way.

Comment: The code replaces any arbitrary line break character with `\n`. I don't understand what a *line break* is in your question. Please add the source and the expected result.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what i am looking for.

Comment: @JochenÖsterreicher Sorry Jochen, the source is just a screenshot. It doesn't show the way how the line breaks are treated. Please get the text from the text view / label and print it.

Comment: let str = textView.text.debugDescription
            let start = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            let end = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
            let range = start..<end
str.substring(with: range) 
i use this now, but is this the best way?

Comment: `joined(separator:"\n")` definitely inserts LF (`\n`) characters between each item of the array. Once again: what is *linebreak*? Please make `Data` from the string in the text view `(let data = textView.text.data(using: .utf8)` and print it: `print(data as NSData)`